# How to read a infeasible result in pyomo using cplex

Tags: cplex, pyomo

I turned off the presolve because i need to get a result but when the result is infesiable and i try to read the result all the result that the program read are 0.

Someone knows how to read it??

Comment: of what possible value is an infeasible result?  `pyomo` variables hold the last value when the solver quits, so if you must, inspect the variables...

Comment: when i get this result:                                                                                                 
Dual simplex - Infeasible:  Objective =  2.9016000002e+04
Solution time =    0.30 sec.  Iterations = 256 (0)
Infeasible variable = slack c_e_x19140_
Deterministic time = 245.10 ticks  (825.27 ticks/sec)                                                                    I get the result of the last iteration or if it is the first i dont get any result

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is export into a mps file from pyomo and then import in docplex and then tun the relaxation CPLEX tool:

See [Infeasible Solution Handling with Python cvxpy and Python_MIP() (CBC solver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67396202/infeasible-solution-handling-with-python-cvxpy-and-python-mip-cbc-solver/67396359#67396359)